# Tricky Logic: Total time to complete the task

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Claire can finish the the task in $5$ hours, Ruth can finish it in $7$ hours. If Clair works for $1$ hour alone, then Ruth joins her to finish the task. What is the total time to complete the task?

Answer: let $t$ = number of hours Claire & Ruth work together.
         $$(t+1)/5 + t/7 = 1 \tag{*}\label{*}$$
The total time is $(t + 1)$ hours.

I don't understand the equation $\eqref{*}$. May anyone explain it to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the amount of work to be done. Then the rates of works per hour of Claire and Ruth are:
$$\frac{X}{5} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{X}{7}.$$
For example, if the task is to solve $35$ problems, Claire will solve $7$ problems per hour and Ruth will solve $5$ problems per hour.

Now the problem states that Claire works for an hour. Then Ruth joins and they work together to complete the task. So, the total time is $t+1$ for Claire and $t$ for Ruth. We make up an equation:
$$\frac{X}{5}\cdot (t+1)+\frac{X}{7}\cdot t=X \ \ \  \stackrel{\text{divide by}X}\Rightarrow \ \ \ \ \frac{t+1}{5}+\frac{t}{7}=1.$$
Is it clear now? Once you solve the equation and find $t$, will it be the final answer or $t+1$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a clear-crystal explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The rates at which Claire and Ruth work are $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{7}$ tasks per hour respectively. With Claire working for an hour, they have $\frac{4}{5}$ of the task remaining. So the total time to complete the task will be a time t to complete the remaining $\frac{4}{5}$ of the task plus $1$ hour $(t+1)$.

Looking at the equation you stated........

$\frac{t+1}{5} + \frac{t}{7} = 1$

$\frac{7(t+1)+5t}{35} = 1$

$7(t+1)+5t = 35$

$12t + 7 = 35$

$12t = 28$

$t = 2\frac{1}{3}$

$t+1 = 3\frac{1}{3}\text{hrs}$ ....  is the total time to complete the task.

I would have done it differently but get the same answer.

$t+1 = \frac{\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}} + 1$

$t+1 = \frac{\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{12}{35}} + 1$

$t+1 = \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{35}{12} + 1$

$t+1 = \frac{7}{3}+1$

$t+1 = 3\frac{1}{3}$ hrs